# QTableView - how to learn which items are selected in a sorted table?

Tags: qt

I have a `QTableView table`. The data for the table is provided by a `QStandardItemModel model`, but the data may be sorted by `QSortFilterProxyModel`. That is:

```
auto *header = ui.table->horizontalHeader();
// ... some configuration of header
auto *sorted = new QSortFilterProxyModel(window);
QObject::connect(header, &QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged, sorted, &QSortFilterProxyModel::sort);
sorted->setSourceModel(model);
ui.table->setModel(sorted);
```

All elements that I insert in a table are `QStandardItem`, added like this:

```
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem("some data");
model->appendRow({item});
```

Now, as the user selects rows, I would like to know which `QStandardItems` are selected. I tried like this:

```
QObject::connect(ui.table->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, this,
                 [this](const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected) {
    QModelIndexList selectedIdxs = selected.indexes();
    for(QModelIndex &idx : selectedIdxs) {
        QStandardItem* item = model->item(idx.row());
        //'item' is what I need, do something with it
    }
});
```

It worked fine at first. However, as soon as I sorted the array, I realised that the row indices is not where they should be! If the element after sorting is first, `idx.row()` seem to return 0, but the `model` does not know anything about sorting.

So my question is, how to translate the sorted indices into the original ones? I was hoping to find a similar function returning a `QStandardItem*` like `QSortFilterProxyModel::item` - but it is not there.

Or maybe there is a more standard way of doing it, without the row indices whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the code in your lambda...

```
[this](const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
  {
    QModelIndexList selectedIdxs = selected.indexes();
    for (QModelIndex &idx: selectedIdxs) {
      QStandardItem *item = model->item(idx.row());
      //'item' is what I need, do something with it
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the `QModelIndex` `idx` is associated with the `QSortFilterProxyModel` rather than the `QStandardItemModel`.  That being the case you need to make use of [`QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource) to map `idx` to the corresponding `QModelIndex` in the `QStandardItemModel`.  Assuming the containing class has a `QSortFilterProxyModel *` data member named `sorted` the code would become...

```
[this](const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
  {
    QModelIndexList selectedIdxs = selected.indexes();
    for (QModelIndex &idx: selectedIdxs) {
      auto source_idx = sorted->mapToSource(idx);
      QStandardItem *item = model->item(source_idx.row());
      //'item' is what I need, do something with it
    }
  }
```

Further to the above you can write a function that iteratively maps the model index until the associated model is no longer a proxy model.  Something like (untested)...

```
QModelIndex map_to_source (QModelIndex index)
{
  const auto *model = index.model();
  for (const auto *pm = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel *>(model); pm;
       pm = dynamic_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel *>(model)) {
    index = pm->mapToSource(index);
    model = pm->sourceModel();
  }
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store those indices as a list of [QPersistentModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html#details).

> A QPersistentModelIndex is a model index that can be stored by an
>   application, and later used to access information in a model. Unlike
>   the QModelIndex class, it is safe to store a QPersistentModelIndex
>   since the model will ensure that references to items will continue to
>   be valid as long as they can be accessed by the model.

Since you are using `QSortFilterProxyModel`, you may also employ `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource()` to store the actual items of the source model, they should not be invalidated upon sorting a proxy model. Then, you can do the converse action and get the proxy items via `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapFromSource` later when you need to do operations with them.